# ios -swift how to catch users' location information

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController , CLLocationManagerDelegate{
    
    let locationmanager = CLLocationManager() 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        locationmanager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationmanager.delegate = self         
        locationmanager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers 
        locationmanager.requestLocation() 
        
        
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let longitude = locations.[0].coordinate.longitude
        let latitude = locations.[0].coordinate.latitude
    }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        
    }
}
```

I am getting errors in didUpdatelocation methods as shown in the below image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ed3XI.png)

Comment: I am a beginner. The problem appears in let longitude and let latitude , I don't know why and how to solve this problem, please help

Comment: Remove the “.” Between the “s” and “[“

Answer (score 1):

Replace didUpdateLocation method implementation with:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        
        let longitude = locations.first?.coordinate.longitude
        let latitude = locations.first?.coordinate.latitude
}
```